# Literally canvas save as png

Tags: javascript, html

I having problem to save my drawing as PNG using literally canvas, whenever i click the save as png button it only took me to the other tab with "about:blank".

- button

  ```
  <button id='save'>Save as PNG</button>
  ```
- canvas

  ```
   var lc = LC.init(document.getElementsByClassName('my-drawing')[0]
  ```
- save function

  ```
    document.getElementById('save').onclick = function(e){
          e.preventDefault();
          window.open(lc.getImage().toDataURL());
             }
  ```

Comment: 1) which browser 2) how does the beginning of the generated uri look like

Comment: @emix google chrome, it just show about:blank

Comment: I can tell by your question. But what does `lc.getImage().toDataURL()` return.

Comment: @emix sorry, i just start programming, but what do you mean "return"? When i click it only show blank page on other tab.

Comment: try this link http://literallycanvas.com/examples/export.html

Comment: @ChintuYadavSara i tried, it still give tme the about:blank. Is it my browser's problem? Is it working fine for you?

Answer (score 0):

I'm able to save my Literally Canvas drawing using the following as an extra button outside of the LC UI, but for some reason I can't for the life of me turn it into a toolbar button within the LC react.js UI without it erroring out in some way:

```
<div class="my-drawing"></div>
<button onClick="saveToFile()">Save</button>

<script>
var lc = LC.init(document.getElementsByClassName('my-drawing')[0];

function saveToFile() {
    var filename = prompt("Save your drawing as:","drawing.png");
    if (filename) {
        filename = "drawing.png";
        lc.getImage().toBlob(function(blob) {
        saveAs(blob, filename);
        });
    }
}
</script>
```

Working in Chrome 76 and Firefox 68. I'm using [filesaver.js](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/) for the file handling.